# find position of sequences of the same character in a line

Tags: string, algorithm, search, substring

This seems to be extremely simple, but if I've got a mental block.
I have a string which contains, say, only '_' and 'x', and I need to find backwards positions of all x-sequences:

```
xxx___xxx___xxx
___x__xxx_xxx__
```

What is the fastest approach? Should I use KMP or BM or it's an overkill?

Comment: what's wrong with scanning the string letter by letter?

Comment: I agree with a linear scan: you cannot beat O(n) as you have at least to read the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scan the string letter by letter. Here's the pseudocode in python:

```
 prev = ''
 # enumerate(collection) enumerates collection elements along with their indices
 # in the form of tuple (index, element)
 # in python strings are collections of characters
 for i, c in enumerate(string):  
     if c == 'x' and c != prev:
          print "found x sequence at position %d" % i # (this prints out the index)
     prev = c
```

Comment: I think you should explain what `enumerate` does, since the OP doesn't tell you that he knows Python.

Comment: @phimeume he could have googled it, but I'll add it for the clarity